# Piramidial representation of constant numbers like pi, euler, golden ratio

Tags: python, math

I can't find it on the internet but a piramidial representation of a constant goes as follows:

There are n rows, nummered from top to bottom, on the i-th floor (i = 1, 2, ... , n) are an i amount of numbers and each number is the sum of the next i numbers in the constant.

[example of a piramidial representation for pi with 5 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqks9.png)

We get the constant and the amount of rows as input and we then need this pyramid as output.
I know I have to use 2 for-loops but I get really confused with how I should use them.

```
cte = input()
verdiep = int(input())
for i in range(1, verdiep+1):
    pyramid = 0
    rij = ''
    for sum in range(i, len(cte)):
        if cte[i] != '.':
            pyramid += int(cte[i])
            rij += str(pyramid)
    print(rij)
```

This is my code so far, I know I shouldn't use in range(i, len(cte)) in my 2nd for-loop but I have no idea how to do this without going to 3 for loops because then I think my program just crashes because it takes too long. How do I get the index for my constant?

Answer (score 0):

my first observation about those pyramid is, at every step, it takes step^2 amount of symbols from given sequence.

in pix you share above, pyramid level^2 (from top, starting from 1) digits from pi.

we can program it as follows

```
b = 31415926535897936 # assume we have such number
step = 1
stop = 3 # pyramid level - from top
start = 0

while step <= stop:
    end = start + step**2
    c = str(b)
    row = c[start:end]
    row_blocks = [{'numbers': [i for i in xs], 'sum': sum(int(i) for i in xs)} for xs in in_groups(row, step)]
    print(row_blocks)
    start = end
    step += 1
```

outputs a result like,

```
[{'numbers': ['3'], 'sum': 3}]
[{'numbers': ['1', '4'], 'sum': 5}, {'numbers': ['1', '5'], 'sum': 6}]
[{'numbers': ['9', '2', '6'], 'sum': 17}, {'numbers': ['5', '3', '5'], 'sum': 13}, {'numbers': ['8', '9', '7'], 'sum': 24}]
```

p.s.

`in_groups` is a helper method which behaves like that

```
>>> [i for i in in_groups('1234567890', 3)]
['123', '456', '789', '0']
>>> [i for i in in_groups('1234567890', 2)]
['12', '34', '56', '78', '90']
```

function body

```
def in_groups(iterable, size):
    for i in range(0,len(iterable), size):
        yield iterable[i: i+size]
```

i'm sure itertools has an alternative but can not memorize right now.

Comment: How should I edit it so the output is something like:
3
5 6
17 13 24
...

Comment: edit `row_blocks = ..` line. remove `{'numbers': [i for i in xs] `

Comment: I mean the numbers now get added on a row with a ',' and are in between [...]
[3] 
[5, 6] 
[17, 13, 24] 
[17, 20, 16, 20] 
[24, 29, 28, 25, 15]
this is my outcome but the expected outcome is:
3
5 6
17 13 24
17 20 16 20
24 29 28 25 15